# Count rows in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I count rows in a table that meet a condition. Below counts every row regardless of whether or not a condition is met.

```
model IEnumerable<Sales1.Models.UserProfile>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
```

### Total Sales Figures

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

foreach(var item in Model){

    if (item.Device_DeviceID != null)
    {
        @Model.Count()


    }
```

}
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Model.Count(x => x.Condition == Value)
```

If your condition is the `Device_DeviceID` not null, it became:

```
@Model.Count(x => x.Device_DeviceID != null)
```

Note that in your case, you don't need the foreach loop to do this.

Comment: You can do 2 Count() and the substract them... or use one Count() crafting the correct set of conditions.

Comment: I get an error (when I run project) count from another table e.g. @Model.Count(x => x.AnotherTable.Condition ==Value) Tables are joined by FK